# How to rstrip only when the object is not "None type"

Tags: python

findloc is another subroutine i created,when parse is called sometimes it returns None and sometimes a value, when trying to rstrip I am getting the following error?how to use rstrip only when the object is non "nonetype" or please suggest any other method.

```
    build_loc=parse(findloc(targetmeta_cid).strip())
    Target_list.append(build_loc.rstrip('\r\n'))
```

Error

```
 Target_list.append(build_loc.rstrip('\r\n'))AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Comment: What does it mean if `parse` returns None? Is it an error? What should happen? You need to answer this question before you can decide how to handle the case properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can this

```
if build_loc is not None:
    Target_list.append(build_loc.rstrip('\r\n'))
```

in order to make it work. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Target_list.append( build_loc.rstrip('\r\n') if build_loc is not None else None )
```

or

```
build_loc = parse(findloc(targetmeta_cid).strip()) or ''
```

---

The cleaner way might be to make sure `parse` doesn't return `None` though!